# Truffle: how to get balance of any address or contract's address

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testing

For example I have a testing block like this:

```
contract('CreeptomaPresale', function(accounts) {
    describe("adopted over allow quantity", function () {
        it("test get balance", async function () {
            let instance = await CreeptomaPresale.deployed();
            console.log("deployed address:" +  address)
        });
    });
});
```

I can get deployed address. But now, I don't know how to get balance of this address or any other addresses.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try

```
contract('CreeptomaPresale', function(accounts) {
    describe("adopted over allow quantity", function () {
        it("test get balance", async function () {
            let instance = await CreeptomaPresale.deployed();
            console.log("deployed address:" +  instance.address);
            let balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(instance.address)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. Can I have a little question: I write a payable function (sending transfer money from sender to contract's owner). My question is: I have list of accounts. which accounts is being used. thanks :D

Comment: The first one. Truffle does some setup, and you're neatly passing `accounts` into your test. Transactions are signed `{from: accounts[0]}` by default. As a matter of style, I like to set up some vars for roles like `owner=accounts[0]`, `funder=`, `sponsor=`, etc. up front and then specify who is talking every step of the way, e.g. `{from: funder1}`

Comment: thanks so much. I have used this style, but it seems not work. can you take a look for me in this post. thanks.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46066/account-balance-does-not-decrease-after-send-ether

Comment: This should be instance.address not address

Answer (score 6):

For newer versions of Truffle, according to the example, it should actually be:

```
let balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(instance.address);
```

Otherwise, you will get the following error:

> ReferenceError: address is not defined