# Account balance does not decrease after send ether

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testing

For example here is my example function in smart contract:

```
function adoptCreeptomas(uint256 beastQuantity, address referrer
) public payable whenNotPaused {
    msg.sender.transfer(50);
}
```

And then I try to test this contract:

```
describe("adopted creeptoma", async function() {
    it('adopted', async function() {
        let instance = await CreeptomaPresale.deployed();

        let pre = convertEther(getBalance(investor));
        await instance.adoptCreeptomas.call(beastQuantity, 0 {from: investor, value: ether(100)});
        let after = convertEther(getBalance(investor));
        console.log("before: " + pre + "--after: " + after);
    });
});
```

The printing log is: `before: 100--after: 100`

Here is my `getBalance` method:

```
export function getBalance(address) {
    return web3.eth.getBalance(address)
}
```

I don't know why balance of account doesn't decrease. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are saying `call()` when you `adoptCreeptomas`. `call()` makes it explicitly a read-only, not state-changing, dry-run operation. It is not signed or sent to the network for mining, so the next time you look, nothing has changed.

Have a look over here for detailed explanation. [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call/770#770)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. There is a point that I don't understand.  I see that my balance is decreased by a number pushed into contract. for example: `{from: investor, value: ether(15)}` but not my number in method transfer. for example: `msg.sender.transfer(10);` So is that means all ether will be consumed by function in contract ? thanks.

Comment: I think because my method will always consume all ether from the input. But I am not sure. If in this case, how can I avoid this so I won't use all user's ether.

Comment: First things first. You should ganache-cli or your own private chain so experimentation doesn't cost anything. The ether will go from the `from` address to the `to` address if the transaction is successful.